# pip not working

Tags: python, ubuntu-10.04, pip

I am trying to install python-shapely with pip in Ubuntu 10.04. I got "Unknown or unsupported command 'install'" while I tried,

`user@desktop:~$ pip install Shapely`

I tried installing pip and got the following error:

```
user@desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install python-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-pip
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 396 not upgraded.
Need to get 0B/49.8kB of archives.
After this operation, 270kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 252574 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking python-pip (from .../python-pip_0.3.1-1ubuntu2.1_all.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/python-pip_0.3.1-1ubuntu2.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/pip', which is also in package pip 0:0.13-1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-pip_0.3.1-1ubuntu2.1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'd appreciate any comment/solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Did you install pip first, then get this error, then try to install python-pip?

If so, first remove pip (apt-get remove pip), then install python-pip instead and try again.

(I just had the same problem, not sure if python 2.7 uses pip and 2.6 uses python-pip?  That might be the issue.)

Comment: Update: python-pip works, but it's an old version.  You're best off downloading the latest version of pip from the interwebs: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip#downloads

Answer (score 5):

Same happen to me, I'm running Ubuntu Lucid Lynx, 10.04 and there's a packaging conflict. Package pip (pearl installation software) has a conflict with the python-pip package. Both of them try to put a pip binary at /usr/bin/pip. You could do several things to solve the problem so choose the one that fits your needs:

1.- Remove "the pearl pip" if you don't use it and install the python pip

2.- Force installation of python pip with some "dpkg -f" or so, but this way your pip binary file will be overwritten

3.- Manually install ether of the packages changing the binary name, i.e. you manually install the python pip and instead of pip you just call the binary "python-pip"

Comment: Option 1 is the best route, apt-get remove pip; apt-get install python-pip.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be broken download. Did you try easy_install?

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

Comment: Yes, I did and it says "Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pip-1.0.2-py2.6.egg" but while I tried "pip install Shapely", am still getting "Unknown or unsupported command 'install'".

Comment: Hi.The culprit is probably Strawberry Perl. I would suggest checking to see if it is installed. If so, you could move it farther down the path, i.e., "behind" (reading left to right) your Python entry.

Answer (score 0):

The problem raise because pip is in strawberry perl and Python both, if Perl's pip hit this error comes

$ which pip
/cygdrive/c/strawberry/perl/bin/pip

Solution
1. C:\Python27\Scripts\pip install south 
or
2. Keep python path before strawberry perl
or 
3. remove strawberry perl path from path variable...

Answer (score 0):

Leave everything, Install latest version of python from its https://www.python.org/downloads .It already contain PIP, so open CMD from start and give him path to reach folder where python is installed and open "Script" folder where pip is build-in installed e.g. *c:\Python36-32\Script* And then write **pip install module_name** and enjoy,,,

Possibly you will have to open Administrator CMD, SO after typing cmd in start when you see CMD is on list press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER and press OK in pop-up dialog and you will have administrative CMD.