# pip not working on windows python 2.7.9

Tags: python-2.7, pip

I've installed Python 2.7.9, which comes with already bundled with pip. I've check that it's there in the modules list. 
But when I run `pip install`  
I get 
`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

With install highlighted as the error?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 17):

Seems like you are running `pip install` from Python interactive console. Instead, you should run it from Windows console (cmd or PowerShell):

```
python2.exe -m pip install <package_name>
```

Where `python2.exe` is executable for Python2.7.9 (you may need to include full path to the executable file) and `<package_name>` is the name of package you want to install

Answer (score 8):

Append `C:\Python27\Scripts;`in **PATH** variable

where `C:\Python27\Scripts;` is the path where **pip script** is located.

Comment: It seems only `C:\Python27` is added to the `PATH` variable by the Python setup, I wonder if it's always been this way.. Just had the same scenario now from the 2.7.13 setup.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and got to know that the error is because it is not able to find the pip.exe to execute.
You need to check the path : **C:\Python27\Scripts**
There, you will find the .exe file and if you run the command from that folder, the command should not give you the error or while running the command, please provide entire path instead of just pip command.

Answer (score 0):

just put python before pip

```
python pip install <package_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

To install try the following command:

```
python.exe -m install web.py
```

Answer (score 0):

what i would suggest is navigate to the location where pip is located and try with the following command :
Pip install 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6sfM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to install Python Modules? I really did many tries, So Finally reached on point to install Python3.6. It offers most easiest way to install it's modules, Try this way
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46652413/8145641

Answer (score -1):

Soon's anwser worked for me, with slight difference, without 2 after python:

```
python.exe -m pip install <package_name>
```

What I don't understand, is that this should be equal to the command in interactive console as following, isn't it ?

```
pip -m install <pachage_name>
```